# Unity how to show loading dialog with script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to show a loading spinner in my unity game. But I can't get it work. It looks like this:

[image]

Loading script code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Loading : MonoBehaviour
{
 public static GameObject load;

 public static void show(){
load.SetActive(true);
}
 public void hide(){
load.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

And then to show it I am using this code:

```
Loading.show();
```

But I am getting this error:
**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this?

Comment: what is your load game object .. why is it static?

Comment: I dont know. I just want to show the loading box on top of the game. Maybe I should do it in another way.

Comment: Um, its your game object if dont know what it is.. how on earth would we?  as you never set it.. thats whats null..

Comment: Thank you. But it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Don't make the gameObject `static` ... *IF* you want this to be a singleton then rather make the component itself have a static reference: `public class Loading : MonoBehavior { public static Loading Instance { get; private set; } private void Awake(){ if(Instance) { Destroy(gameObject); return; } Instance = this; DontDestroyOnLoad(this); } public void Show(bool show){ gameObject.SetActive(show); } }` and then use it like `Loading.Instance.Show(true);`